# Changing Password with Update Command

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database

I attempted to code the password change logic by using sql update-set-where command but I discovered that it doesn't work with my code. No error message was flagged but on checking the database I would discover that the column data still remains the same. Please kindly let me know where I am getting it wrong.

```
def updatePwd(self):
  con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="db")
  with con:
     cur = con.cursor()

     username = self.ui.userlineEdit.text()
     old_password = self.ui.oldpwdlineEdit.text()
     new_password = self.ui.newpwdlineEdit.text()
     new_password2 = self.ui.new2pwdlineEdit.text()

     cmd1 = "SELECT username, password FROM persons WHERE username = %s AND password = SHA1(%s)"

     cur.execute(cmd1, (username, old_password,))

     row = cur.fetchone()

     if row == None:
        self.ui.response_label.setText("Incorrect username or password")
     else:
        if new_password == new_password2:
            cmd2 = "UPDATE persons SET password = SHA1(%s) WHERE username = %s"
            cur.execute(cmd2, (new_password, username,))
            self.ui.response_label.setText("Logged in successful")
        else:
            self.ui.response_label.setText("The two passwords do not match")
```

Comment: Is that the complete code of that function? Isn't it missing a `commit`?

Comment: The connection context manage automatically closes the connection, but it does not automatically commit it.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I now added the commit and it worked! Thank you all!